# How do I dynamically allocate a 2d array of chars?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, char, malloc

I want to dynamically allocate a 2d array to store strings.

I originally declared the array like this:

```
char lines[numlines][maxlinelength];
```

This however gives me a stack overflow when numlines is very huge.

How can I dynamically allocate it to prevent stack overflow?

Comment: arr = malloc(numlines[star]maxlinelength[star]sizeof(char));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
char **arr;
int i;
arr = malloc(numlines*sizeof(char*));
for (i = 0; i < numlines; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(maxlinelength*sizeof(char));
```

This will give you a pointer to pointer, but you can handle it as if it was a 2D array.

Also see [this very useful link](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/) in order to understand what dynamic allocation for 2D arrays actually does in the memory.

Comment: That is not a 2D array.  It's an array of pointers to 1D arrays.

Comment: @MartinJames but the only way to allocate a 2D array dynamically is to actually allocate a double pointer..

Comment: @Martin - yes, you're right.  However, it is a pointer that can be used *as if* it is a 2D array (until the dynamically allocated memory is reallocated or released)

Comment: @Marievi - As I suggested with another answer, it is less error prone to use the idiom `X = malloc(number * sizeof(*X))` rather than hard-coding the types.   Also, you're missing a closing `)` in the `malloc()` call within the loop.

Comment: @Marievi: That is wrong! You can very well have `int (*p)[varcols] = malloc(...);`

Comment: @Peter thanks for your remarks, I edited my post. What do you mean "hardcoding the types"?

Comment: @Olaf yes, you are of course right, but this is what I thought of proposing.

Comment: @Olaf - it's actually an alternative response to the question, rather than wrong.  There are a number of possible answers to the question as asked, all with respective advantages and disadvantages in practice, and this is one of those.

Comment: @Marievi - by "hardcoding the types" I mean that you have provided the type name as operand to `sizeof`.   Instead you could do `arr = malloc(numlines*sizeof(*arr))` and `arr[i] = malloc(maxlinelength*sizeof(*arr[i]))`.    The compiler will correctly deduce the types.   If you change `arr` to `wchar_t **arr`, your approach means you have to remember to update the `malloc()` calls to ensure the correct sizes are allocated.   This idiom avoids that need.

Comment: @Peter: OP asks about allocating a 2D array, the answer show a very different construct. Worse, it does not explain it but states "you can handle it as if it was a 2D array.", which is wrong! Try e.g `sizeof(*arr)`. It just uses the same syntax. Note that identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: Just checked the link: This is nonsense, too. See the code in the answer of @2501 for a 2D array.

Comment: @Olaf - I didn't write this answer.   I'm expressing disagreement with you that there is a single right answer (the one you're advocating) and that all others are wrong.   With EVERY possible solution, it is possible to find a test case that shows a difference from an actual 2D array.

Comment: @Peter: C provides **one** way to implement a 2D array, i.e. an "array of arrays" and two ways to handle it dynamically: Use a pointer to 2D array or a pointer to the first entry. As the first requires explicit dereferencing and compicates the syntax, but has no other advantage the second is typically used. But none has impact on the structure or semantics of the memory block. Which something like `Type **` has (it has other applications, e.g. if you need variable row-lengths). So, no, there are not multiple ways for a 2D array.

Comment: My disagreement stands.  You are dismissing anything that doesn't comply with your narrow perspective, so no point in my discussing further.

Answer (score 3):

Use a pointer to an array:

```
#define maxlinelength 10
char (*lines)[maxlinelength] = malloc( sizeof( char[maxlinelength] ) * numlines ) ;
lines[0][0] = 'A' ;
```

This requires that the inner most size, `maxlinelength`, is constant.

You can avoid this limitation if you use pointers to variable-length arrays in which case the syntax remains the same and `maxlinelength` doesn't have to be a constant. Standards that supports this feature, are C99 and optionally C11.

( A *constant* is a variable whose value is known at compile time.)

( And to clarify: `sizeof( *lines )` is identical to `sizeof( char[maxlinelength] )` )

Answer (score -1):

You may allocate a *contiguous* block of memory with the following:

```
const int numlines = 10;
const int maxlinelength = 120;
const int arrlen = sizeof(char) * numlines * maxlinelength;
const char **lines = (const char**)malloc(arrlen);

fprintf(stderr, "Allocated %d bytes\n", arrlen);
```

Add/remove `const` and typecasting according to taste.

Comment: The problem with this is that `lines[i]` does not point to (the first character of) an array of `char`, so `lines[i][j]` doesn't work as if it is accessing a 2D array.