# Why can't I use my 2d array of RectangleShapes properly?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my drawTile function. Here, I declare my 2d array of RectangleShapes where I pass the same RectangleShape r into each location.

```
void board::drawTile(RenderWindow &window, int x2, int y2){
    RectangleShape r;

    RectangleShape rectArray[y2][x2]; //I've already defined rectArray above in my class

    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < y2; i2++){
        for(int ii2 = 0; ii2 < x2; ii2++){
            rectArray[i2][ii2] = r;
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this, it's giving me following error:

```
"no match for operator[]' (operator types are 'sf::RectangleShape' and 'int').
```

I can't tell what's wrong.

```
int main(){ 
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800,800), "Window");
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
    board callFunc;
    board rectArrayObj;
    callFunc.drawTile(window, x, y);
    rectArrayObj.rectArray[column][row].setFiilColor(Color::Red);
}
```

Comment: you have to dynamically allocate the `rectArray` using `new` / `malloc`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically allocate a 2d array of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354800/how-do-i-dynamically-allocate-a-2d-array-of-chars)

Comment: It seems like you expect `board` to contain a _member_ called `rectArray`; however, we can't see the declaration of `board` to confirm. I am verging a guess to say it does have that member, and instead you are creating a local `rectArray` in `board::drawTile`. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: All we know is that `RectangleShape rectArray[y2][x2];` is not `rectArrayObj.rectArray`. Unrelated note: `RectangleShape rectArray[y2][x2];` isn't kosher C++. This might be what @RatulSharker is getting at, but rather than `new`/`delete`, I suggest `std::vector`