# How to reuse a *char[] in a loop?

Tags: c

Writing POSIX C (or at least trying to) to run on a typical modern desktop computer.

I've tried searching SO and Google but I don't think I know enough to get the correct search terms.

My program does the following:

- Reads lines from a text file.
- Line is added to a `*char[1000]` called `hay` (as in, haystack).
- Once 1000 lines have been added to `hay`, `hay` is passed to a pthread.

The bit I can't figure out is:

- How do I "reinitialise" `hay` so that it points to a new `char[1000]`?

This is because I want my main thread to keeping reading lines and dispatch the next 1000 to another thread.

Currently I have this:

```
#define ITEMS_PER_THREAD 1000
// <SNIP>
char *hay[ITEMS_PER_THREAD];
for (int i=0; i<ITEMS_PER_THREAD; i++) {
    hay[i] = malloc(256);
    if (hay[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[E] Couldn't allocate memory for haystack item!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
// <SNIP some definitions...>
size_t hay_count = 0;
while((read = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
    strcpy(hay[hay_count], line);
    hay_count++;
    if (hay_count == ITEMS_PER_THREAD) {
        // Start worker thread
        sem_wait(&semWorkers);
        pthread_t new_pt = dispatch(hay, hay_count); // function to create the thread
        pthread_join(new_pt, NULL);
        hay_count = 0; // reset the counter
        // What goes here?? How do I get a "new" *hay[ITEMS_PER_THREAD]??
    }
}
```

Comment: *How do I "reinitialise" hay*. You need to dynamically allocate `hay` itself and not just the items in `hay`. So that each thread gets a different array. See: [How do I dynamically allocate a 2d array of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354800/how-do-i-dynamically-allocate-a-2d-array-of-chars)

Comment: You malloc storage for `hay`(i.e., the pointer array) the same way as each individual array for a line. Just once per 1000 lines. Freeing the storage is another matter...

Comment: You can also, for efficiency and locality, allocate a block of 256*1000 chars right away and fill an array of pointers with the addresses arr+i*256 (i from 0..999). But that does not relieve you of storing the addresses array. If you have control over the thread API you could pass *a single pointer* to the beginning of the 256*1000 block, and the thread moves in 1000-steps on its own.

Comment: Hmm, I think kaylum and Peter are recommending the same thing. I think you're recommending `char *hay[ITEMS_PER_THREAD]` becomes `char **hay`? Assuming that's what you mean, I need to have a play with that because my gut feeling is that `realloc`ing `hay` will free "old" `hay` which the thread could still need. I need to play/think :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest might be to do `char* hay[n][ITEMS_PER_THREAD];` where `n` is the number of threads. Then you give each thread one pointer to `hay[i]` and tell it to go work on that.

For example you could feed these pointers to each thread through the `pthread_create` arguments, even before there's data available. Then have all threads sleeping until there's work to be done.

For larger programs you might want to look into thread pools - that is, a "design pattern" that distributes work between many threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Lundin. I see how this works, but I think I prefer the idea of building the array and sending it to the thread to deal with, rather than a dimension per thread.

Comment: @Bridgey No matter how you do it, you need to let the thread know the bounds it should stick inside.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @Peter and @kaylum, I declare and initialise `hay` like this:

```
char **hay;
hay = malloc(ITEMS_PER_THREAD * sizeof(char*));
if (hay == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[E] Couldn't allocate memory for haystack hash!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And then in my `while` loop I re-`malloc` it:

```
while((read = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
    strcpy(hay[hay_count], line);
    hay_count++;
    if (hay_count == ITEMS_PER_THREAD) {
        // Start worker thread
        sem_wait(&semWorkers);
        pthread_t new_pt = dispatch(needles, needle_count, hay, hay_count...);
        pthread_join(new_pt, NULL);
        hay_count = 0;
        hay = malloc(ITEMS_PER_THREAD * sizeof(char*));
        if (hay == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[E] Couldn't allocate memory for haystack hash!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        // <SNIP>
    }
```

`hay` is then `free`d in the thread.
This seems to work.